# Is Unity game engine right for me?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I want to start developing games for fun(nothing too proffesional), and I have no experience in that field at all. 
I know C# well and a little bit of C, and I've heard that Unity is recommended.
I have no knowledge in graphics and such, and I want to spend as little as possible time on doing graphic-related work. What interests me is coding.

My question is - is Unity right for me?
Is there another engine you might recommend?

Comment: Is something right for you? Only you can answer that question, since we don't know you so well. Besides, this kind of questions might not help any future visitors, and this is kind of not how this site works.

Answer (score 4):

I have been working with Unity, with only having experience in C#.... I have found it to be a really good engine to work with. It can be really simple to get things off the ground, and it can also be as complex as you want it to be...

Also, in the Unity website, there are a lot of good resources to get the basic hang of it!

[Unity Tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules)
[Unity Project Example](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/stealth)